# Equation/Algebra

Tags: problem-solving

Ethan, Mcdonald and Willie earns $\$51700$ a month. Ethan earns $\$400$ less than Mcdonald and Willie earns $\$3000$ more than Ethan. How much do they all earn each?

Mcdonald's earnings is $X$.

Ethan: $x - \$400$

Willie: $x - \$400 + 3000$

I don't know the rest of the proccess.

$$X + x - 400 + x - 400 + 3000 = 57100$$

How do you get what each one of them earns?

Comment: Solve for $x$, and then find $x-400$ and $x+2600$.

Comment: Use better titles, ones that describe the problem better. In this case "solving a system of equations" is far better than "equation/algebra"

Answer (score 0):

You could first set how much Ethan earned as x and make the equation using,
(x+400) <- How much McDonald earns
(x+3000) <- How much Willie earns
Then you have the equation, x+x+x+400+3000=51700. Or 3x+3400=51700. You then do,
3x=51700-3400=48300
x=48300/3
x=16100 (How much Ethan earns)
Then for McDonald:
16100+400=16500
Then for Willie:
16100+3000=19100

Comment: Oh I solved it a different way by mistake, my bad. Do you have to solve it with two separate variables? If not, then u could use my method.